# Who are "the Yechidim"?

Tags: history, synagogue, jewish-american-history

I'm reading a book called "Publications of The American Jewish Historical Society, no. 21" (which can be found for free on [archive.com](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer)). The first part is a collection of records of Congregation Shearith Israel in NY from the years 1728-1760. In it, it's mentioned that different members filled different functions in the running of the shul - there was a chazan, parnasim, chatanim (Beresheet and Torah), and so forth. Then there's a group of people called "the Yechidim" (referred to as "the Yechidimz" in 18th-century Hebrew-to-English transliteration) who would assemble from time to time. Does anyone know what role these people filled in a congregation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>(Note to proofreaders: the typos in the quoted text are all in the original old English document.)</sup>

On [page 268](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer/page/268/mode/2up?q=yechidimz), in the glossary, they define Yechidimz as the *double plural* for Yechidim or Yechedim, Yechidim being defined as **H. Members of the congregation**.

From [page 46](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer/page/n45/mode/2up?q=yechidimz) you see that these Yechidimz had voting rights in the congregation.

> the Parnaz and assistants shall not discharge any of said officers out of their place without first callg all the **Yechidimz** for to Give their vote and the major part shall carry it the Parnaz haveing two Votes.

On [page 45](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer/page/4/mode/2up?q=yechidimz) you see that part of the job of the Shamaz (sic) was to ensure these people were called to shul at the correct time.:

> 4thly That Valentin Campanall Shamaz shall be oblidged to atend at the Sinagog and shall call the Yechidimz that they may assemble togeathere at the usuall hours

So Yechidimz seems to be what we call *the paying members of the congregation*, as can be seen from [page 14](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer/page/14/mode/2up?q=yechidim):

> On the 15th of Sivan [June 19, 1731], the President Daniel Gomez having called a meeting of all the **Yechidim** of the Kahal Kados, it was unanimously resolved, that owing to the failure of the Samas Valentin Campanal to comply with his duties under the pretext that his salary was too small, to pass a resolution by the Parnas and all the other **Yechidim** to increase his salary from £15 to £18 per annum, with the understanding that, in accordance with his contract, if he fails to comply with his duties, as he ought to, he will be fined Five Shillings each time.

And again on [page 216](https://archive.org/details/publicationsofam21amer/page/216/mode/2up?q=members) we see that members were called Yechedim:

> In the early period of the Congregation it was the duty of the Shamas to call the **Yechedim** together at the usual hours, also to Selichot in the morning before daylight, and to Call at their houses on friday afternoon and areb Yomtob: the **members** in those days attended the Synagogue regularly morning & evening: nothing but sickness prevented them, the floor was stone, and no fire therein.